# How to delete lines before a match perserving it?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have the following script to remove all lines before a line which matches with a word:

```
str='
1
2
3
banana
4
5
6
banana
8
9
10
'

echo "$str"  | awk -v pattern=banana '
  print_it {print} 
  $0 ~ pattern {print_it = 1}
'
```

It returns:

```
4
5
6
banana
8
9
10
```

But I want to include the first match too. This is the desired output:

```
banana
4
5
6
banana
8
9
10
```

How could I do this? Do you have any better idea with another command?
I've also tried `sed '0,/^banana$/d'`, but seems it only works with files, and I want to use it with a variable.

And how could I get all lines before a match using awk?
I mean. With banana in the regex this would be the output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just invert the commands in the `awk`:

```
echo "$str"  | awk -v pattern=banana '
  $0 ~ pattern {print_it = 1}   <--- if line matches, activate the flag
  print_it {print}              <--- if the flag is active, print the line
'
```

The `print_it` flag is activated when `pattern` is found. From that moment on (inclusive that line), you print lines when the flag is ON. Previously the `print` was done before the checking.

Comment: Sorry, I clicked in other answer accidentally. :)

Comment: No, no problem at all :) I also think that other answer is shorter, but I just posted based on your original script. Also, note that `-v pattern="banana"` allows you to change the pattern or even give it from a bash variable with `-v pattern=$bash_var`.

Comment: And could you tell me how to get the lines after the match without including it? Thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean? If it is the same question, edit it and show desired output. If it is something very different, it is better to ask a new question.

Comment: I've edited main post. Thanks for the advice, @fedorqui.

Comment: @JohnDoe you can use `echo "$str" | awk '/banana/ {exit} {print}'`

Answer (score 4):

This `awk` should do:

```
echo "$str" | awk '/banana/ {f=1} f'
banana
4
5
6
banana
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thanks! simplest of all!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '/^banana$/,$p'
```

Should do what you want.  `-n` instructs sed to print nothing by default, and the `p` command specifies that all addressed lines should be printed.  This will work on a stream, and is different than the awk solution since this requires the entire line to match 'banana' exactly whereas your awk solution merely requires 'banana' to be in the string, but I'm copying your sed example.  Not sure what you mean by "use it with a variable".  If you mean that you want the string 'banana' to be in a variable, you can easily do `sed -n "/$variable/,\$p"` (note the double quotes and the escaped `$`) or `sed -n "/^$variable\$/,\$p"` or `sed -n "/^$variable"'$/,$p'`.  You can also `echo "$str" | sed -n '/banana/,$p'` just like you do with awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat in.txt | awk "/banana/,0"
```

In case you don't want to preserve the matched line then you can use

```
cat in.txt | sed "0,/banana/d"
```