# How to remove all lines after a line containing some string?

Tags: awk, text, data-manipulation

I need to remove all lines after the first line that contains the word "fox".

For example, for the following input file "in.txt":

```
The quick
brown fox jumps
over
the
lazy dog
the second fox
is hunting
```

The result will be:

```
The quick
brown fox jumps
```

I prefer a script made in awk or sed but any other command line tools are good, like perl or php or python etc.

I am using gnuwin32 tools in Windows, and the solution I could find was this one:

```
grep -m1 -n fox in.txt | cut -f1 -d":" > var.txt
set /p MyNumber=<var.txt
head -%MyNumber% in.txt > out.txt
```

However, I am looking for a solution that is shorter and that is portable (this one contains Windows specific command `set /p`).

Similar questions:

- [How to delete all the lines after the last occurence of pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308594/how-to-delete-all-the-lines-after-the-last-occurence-of-pattern)
- [How to delete lines before a match perserving it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22559017/how-to-delete-lines-before-a-match-perserving-it)
- [Remove all lines before a match with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364951/remove-all-lines-before-a-match-with-sed)
- [How to delete the lines starting from the 1st line till line before encountering the pattern '[ERROR] -17-12-2015' using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377793/how-to-delete-the-lines-starting-from-the-1st-line-till-line-before-encountering)
- [How to delete all lines before the first and after the last occurrence of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62493807/how-to-delete-all-lines-before-the-first-and-after-the-last-occurrence-of-a-stri)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{print} /fox/{exit}' file
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed '0,/fox/!d' file
```

or

```
sed -n '0,/fox/p' file
```

Comment: Those scripts work great, how about deleting the lines after the last match of the word? Shall I ask another question for that?

Comment: Another question: How about deleting lines after match, including the matching line? In the example above, only the first line will be printed - "The quick"

Comment: Yes, I suggest to start a new question.

Comment: Great, I started the question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526188/delete-all-lines-after-the-last-match

Comment: I could not find the duplicate question by myself but now it's linked in the body of this question. Thans. How about the second question - delete lines after match, including matched line?

Comment: This should do the job: `awk 'NR==FNR{if (/fox/) hit=NR; next} FNR==hit{exit} {print}' file file` It's a smal modification to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44309745/3776858).